# help with network setting within ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireshark, nmap

I'm hoping someone can help, I set my router to map MAC address to static IPs last night, around the same time I installed nmap and wireshark to help me setup a proximity sensor within my home assistant docker container.

Since then I've been having issues with my ubuntu server not being able to connect to the internet (ping google.com) and also my wireguard vpn is not connecting as it did. It's probably worth mentioning I also have adguard home installed in its own docker container which doesn't appear to be getting its own host ip address either. Not really sure where to start any advice is appreciated or maybe its best to just to reinstall ubuntu? :/

i have ubuntu 22.04 and its headless, running docker and a bunch of other things in containers..

- ive tried uninstalling nmap and wireshark
- my /etc/resolv.conf file seems to update itself with what seems like an ipv6 address that changes based on whats trying to connect to wireguard vpn.
- if i delete the contents of the /etc/resolv.conf file i can then ping google.com successfully but then the router instantly goes down which is when i need to disconnect the server and reset the router to get the internet back up.

makes it a pain to do anything as i ssh into the box and need the connection...

Best
A

Comment: This seems like an issue with your new router settings. The Ubuntu behaviors you describe seem like symptoms caused by those router settings. Address the cause, not the symptoms.

Comment: ok some more testing, i cannot seem to sort the issue, disabled ipv6 entirely from the router and hasnt really helped, if i login to the ubuntu server and check /etc/resolv.conf it now has the ipv6 looking address in there (presumably after trying to connect to wireguard vpn this updates itself).

when i see this i try to ping google from the ubuntu server and its completely dead interms of connection to the WAN.

Comment: first: it is very unclear what problem you have. second: you are doing too many things at the same time. to sort out the issue you have to go step by step. revert back, what you have done and observe again. is the issue gone? how does resolv.conf look like without error. do you have internet when wireguard is offline? etc...

Comment: ok here where i am at with it,

- fresh ubuntu server install 22.04
- fresh install of docker and started adding the basic programs in containers such as home assistant and portainer

issue is exactly the same as before. when the ubuntu server is plugged into ethernet and turned on the internet is ok for a short period of time and then all internet goes down on all devices connected to the router.

Comment: if i unplug the ubuntu server from ethernet the internet sometimes comes back for all other devices connected to the router, sometimes the internet doesnt come back at all unless i reset the router.

i have tried to change the host name of the new ubuntu install but kept the static ip the same. right now i cant seem to tell if its the ubuntu server thats the issue here or the router or both?

What would you have me to do diagnose this strange issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i changed the ip address of the ubuntu server and so far its working ok, does anyone know what might have been the problem if this indeed is the resolution?

Comment: I’m a bit perplexed on your problem. But you need to solve one thing at a time. Start with the source…your router. Ensure that this is getting an IP on the WAN interface. Any host connected to router and setup with DHCP should be able to grab an IP from the router with default router configuration. If not this host, then any other. Once that is confirmed, focus on this host. Get it working with a default installation. Then, work on other custom configs such as Docker etc.

Comment: Also, there should be no need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`. Default installation is with this file being a symlink pointing to local stub resolver. Enter the following command in a terminal: `ls -l /etc/resolve.conf`. You should see that it points to: `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. Thus, don’t edit this file. If there’s truly a DNS problem, it’s a different issue. So, when connecting host to router, enter `ip a` in a terminal. You’ll be able to see if there’s an IP address associated with your interface. If not, fix that first. If yes, probably problem with DNS, so fix that.